# Emacs Custom Themes changes font color on restart

Tags: emacs, themes

When using `customise-themes` I can set `Save Theme Setting` hopping to see the same settings on restart. But on restart, the font color is black. Always. No matter what custom setting I set. If I re-load the theme with `load-theme`it works just fine.

What can it be? Are there other settings that are loaded after the custom settings?

EDIT:
Here are the only two lines on mi init file (~/.emacs):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/") 
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes")
```

Those are that places where I have the themes. The folders contain ONLY the salarized themes and a dash.el.

Further I **can delete those lines** and set a default theme (such as tango-dark). On restarting, the font color is set to black.

Comment: Is it possible you always have another `load-theme` command in your `init.el` file? That would mess things up. Try not loading your standard `init.el` and make a fresh one with a new theme, and see what happens.

Comment: Show the code you use. Remove everything else from your init file (comment it out), to simplify testing.

Comment: I added the contents of my init file above. The only things there are loading of the folders containing the themes.

Comment: The problems persist if I delete the init file and use a default theme.